# Supabase: Could not read Signup params: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field SignupParams.email of type string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, supabase

I have been trying to setup supabase with email and password to allow users to sign up but somehow I keep getting this error:

```
 AuthApiError: Could not read Signup params: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field SignupParams.email of type string
```

This is my code so far

```
 const signInWithEmail = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
      email: { email },
      password: { password },
      options: {
        data: {
          first_name: "John",
          age: 27,
        },
      },
    });

    error ? console.log(error) : console.log(data);
  };
```

for the form I have this code:

```
 <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
    <div className="grid gap-2">
      <div className="grid gap-1">
        <label className="sr-only" htmlFor="email">
          Email
        </label>
        <input
          id="email"
          placeholder="name@example.com"
          className=""
          type="email"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoComplete="email"
          autoCorrect="off"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          disabled={isLoading}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />

        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Enter a pasword..."
          className=""
          value={password}
          autoComplete="off"
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          signInWithEmail();
        }}
        disabled={loading}
        className=""
      >
        {isLoading && (
          <Icons.spinner className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 animate-spin" />
        )}
        Sign In with Email
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

How can I resolve the error above, I have followed the docs and used the code provided from their but I can seem to overcome this error.

Comment: Solution: Remove {} for email and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have email and password wrapped in {} when they don't need to be.

Your current code

```
email: { email },
password: { password }
```

How it should be

```
email: email,
password: password
```

Comment: Yep, I managed to fix it, I wrote a comment with the fix in my post. 
Though I appreciate your time. So I will mark yours as the answer.